# How to print current total in the column footer of each intermediate page

Tags: jasper-reports

I am designing a report the for the ledger used in accounting. At the end of each group, I have to print the total. For that I can easily do it using the group footer. But when the group is large, it spreads over many pages. The problem is that in intermediate pages there is no total, but only in the last page.

How can I print current total in the column footer of each intermediate page?

Is there any tag or way that I can use in the *Print when expression* to do this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi user, can you expand your post with more details and specifics. Your post is really vague. Please see [ask] and the [faq] for guidance on how to ask a great Stack Overflow question. Good luck! :)

Comment: I am designing a report the for the ledger used in accounting. At the end of each group I have to print the total. For that I can easily do it using the group footer. But when the group is large it spreads over many pages. The problem is that in intermediate pages there is no Total but only in the last page. How can I print current total in the column footer of each intermediate page ? Thanks!!!

Comment: I put that information in your post using this >>[edit]<< link. But you may want to edit and make your last sentence more clear. I wasn't sure what to do with that. Welcome to Stack Overflow, and good luck! :)

Comment: Sure, but I'm still not 100% sure what the problem is. That just might be because I'm not familiar with the technology, but if there is code you can add, for example, that will go a long way to enabling others to help out. Once again, good luck in finding your answers.

Comment: Can you help me to upload the screen shots ? I have less than 10 reputation@jmort253 ?