# How to print Group footer on each page

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Is there any group option in *iReport* to **Print Group Footer on each page**?

This means that the group footer will appear in each page the group appear.

Have a look here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189616/how-to-print-current-total-in-the-column-footer-of-each-intermediate-page)

Answer (score 0):

For page footer to appear in every page use the footer band. Drag and drop a static text/text box and put the footer content in it. you need not use any group option for this.

Comment: Thanks @subiah-r-nagarajan But I want to print the group footer on each page whenever the group spread on many pages. Not the page footer.

Comment: Nope I haven't had a chance to try...this requirement ! But will let you know if I find the answer...Soulemane moumie

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a column footer and have a variable that calculates the sum over the group.  Put this variable in the column footer and leave the evaluation time as Now.  I think this will give you what you are looking for.

Column headers and footers appear on each page.

Answer (score -2):

Add a Report group in Ireport then move all the text and Chart to this group then you can see 
page footer in each pages.

Comment: I want to see the group footer in all pages where the splitted group appers not the page footer.